# Finding Duplicate rows based on a column in Unix File

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a file of about 1 Million records. I need to extract the records which have different FName and LName for id.

**Input File**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,ID,FName,Col5,LName,Col6,Col7,Col8
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,123,Ram,,Kumar,phn1,fax1,url1
AP,abc2@gmail.com,xyz2,abc2,123,Shyam,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,345,Raman,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,345,Raman,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,567,Alex,,Smith,phn2,fax2,url1
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,789,Allen,,Prack,phn2,fax2,url1
```

**The result that I want to see**

```
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,123,Ram,,Kumar,phn1,fax1,url1
AP,abc2@gmail.com,xyz2,abc2,123,Shyam,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
```

Any AWK or Sed command or script can help? Thanks

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Sure. Adding it.

Comment: Could you please do explain why lines `567,Alex,Smith` and `789,Allen,Prack` are NOT present in expected output, though they have their first and last names unique.

Comment: They don't have ids duplicated in file.

Comment: @EdMorton What I want to achieve is that  - For any ID if there are 2 different people (First Name, Last Name) attached to that, want to extract those records from the file. In the example given in question, for ID 123, Ram Kumar and Shyam Kumar  2 different people are associated and for others are not). Not sure why the question isn't conveying the same. Hope this is more clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Please put all information in your question, not spread out in comments where people could miss them. I thought abc1 and abc2 were your ID values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

```
$ awk -F, '
    { vals[$5][$6 FS $8] = $0 }
    END {
        for ( id in vals ) {
            if ( length(vals[id]) > 1 ) {
                for (name in vals[id]) {
                    print vals[id][name]
                }
            }
        }
    }
' file
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,123,Ram,,Kumar,phn1,fax1,url1
AP,abc2@gmail.com,xyz2,abc2,123,Shyam,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
```

or if your input file is sorted by "id" as shown in your sample input then with any awk and without storing the input file in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR > 1 {
    id   = $5
    name = $6 FS $8

    if ( id == prevId ) {
        if ( name != prevName ) {
            if ( firstRec != "" ) {
                print firstRec
                firstRec = ""
            }
            print
        }
    }
    else {
        firstRec = $0
    }

    prevId   = id
    prevName = name
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,123,Ram,,Kumar,phn1,fax1,url1
AP,abc2@gmail.com,xyz2,abc2,123,Shyam,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
```

Comment: First Name and Last Name with different cases (lower and upper) are considering as different names. Anything we can do to ignore cases?

Comment: Again, please don't spread out requirements in comments, put it all in your question (and include a case to test that in yoru example). Having said that, just change `name = $6 FS $8` to `name = tolower($6 FS $8)` to make it case-insensitive

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {id = $5; name = $6 FS $8} id in map && map[id] != name {if (!done[id]++) print rec[id]; print} {map[id] = name; rec[id] = $0}' file

AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,123,Ram,,Kumar,phn1,fax1,url1
AP,abc2@gmail.com,xyz2,abc2,123,Shyam,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
```

Or a bit more readable:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
}
{
   id = $5
   # name variable to store fname, lname
   name = $6 FS $8
}
# if this id is already stored as key in map and if it is there check
# if stored name is different from current name
id in map && map[id] != name {
   # print previous record if not already printed
   if (!done[id]++)
      print rec[id]
   # print current record
   print
}
{
   # store name by key as id in map array
   # and store full record by key as id in rec array
   map[id] = name
   rec[id] = $0
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks . Could you please explain this step - $1 in map && map[$1] != name {
   print $1, map[$1] ORS $0

Comment: This looks perfect to me, just add a `| awk '!seen[$0]++'` to remove duplicates as it may produce a lot otherwise

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your answer. Actually I have other fields too before and after id and Lname... WhatIf the ID is 5th field in file and FName is 6th and LName is 8th.
Also  there are many more fields, How can I print those and considering 5th, 6th and 8th in mind?

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta, IMHO, answers will be always provided by shown samples only, if this answer doesn't work with your actual file and works with shown samples then you need to mention samples which are near to your actual file else it will be difficult to help/guide on this one, so kindly do edit your question with proper details and let us now then, thank you.

Comment: Sorry for trouble. I updated the question as per data.

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta: Check my updated answer. Please provide all the relevant information upfront to get best answers, just a suggestion for future questions.

Comment: @ed-morton et al, Validating the results with my file. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should do the job:

```
awk -F "," '!a[$5] {a[$5]=$0} a[$5]!=$0{print a[$5]; print $0; a[$5]=$0}' input_file.txt
```

Output:

```
AP,abc@gmail.com,xyz1,abc1,123,Ram,,Kumar,phn1,fax1,url1
AP,abc2@gmail.com,xyz2,abc2,123,Shyam,,Kumar,phn2,fax2,url1
```

Note that the entire lines are compared based on ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, -v id="123" '$1 == id { map[NR]=$0 } END { for(i in map) { print map[i] } }' file
```

With awk, set the field separator to a comma and pass a variable in called id. When the first field is equal to the passed id, add to an array called map, indexed by the record number and with the line as the value. At the end loop through the array and print the values.